# request for reference

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

I am currently trying to grasp basic theorems of complex analysis in higher dimensions for different classes of functions. e.g. analytic, harmonic, subharmonic and pluriharmonic. Out of these a lot of references are available except for pluriharmonic(or maybe i havn't been able to find that).
Can anyone tell me any good references for studying definitions and properties of pluriharmonic functions in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and in $\mathbb{C}^n$. \
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to find some references in wiki, 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluriharmonic_function